# javascript code to display div message inside tetxbox

Tags: javascript, php

below is my script to calculate total..

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function calculateTotal() {
        // price per unit 
        var priceEL = document.getElementById('price');
        // get input element from DOM
        var inputEl = document.getElementById('quantity');
        // read quantity from the input element (it is read as a string)

         var priceSting = priceEL.value;
        var quantitySting = inputEl.value;
        // convert string value from the form element into integer (or float if needed)
        var quantity = parseInt(quantitySting);
        var price = parseInt(priceSting);
        // calculate total
        var total = price * quantity;
        // get element that displays total from DOM
        var displayEl = document.getElementById('total')
        // display total value in target element
        displayEl.innerHTML = total;
    }
</script>
```

now my code echo total value inside div tag...like below

```
<div id ="total"></div>
```

**i need to display total inside below textbox....**

```
<input type="textbox" name="total" id ="total"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("total").value = total;
```

Answer (score 1):

remember, use `.value` for all the input fields in HTML, `innerHTML` is used for readonly text fields

for your requirement use:

`displayEl.value= total;`

Comment: this has caught me out a few times, value should work

Answer (score 0):

Change the id of div, you cann't have same Ids for two elements

```
   <div id ="totaldiv"></div>
```

and replace in your javascript

```
displayEl.innerHTML = total;
```

with

```
displayEl.value = total;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per specification two elements should not have same ID attribute assigned.

So change your div ID to something else and try below code:

```
displayEl.value = total;
```